# how to pass a class object as parameter

Tags: c++

so I have two classes representing each a linked list

```
class list1 {

      //some functions

};

class list2 {

      //some functions

}
```

and I have my main function with two object LL1 and LL2 for respectively list1 class and list2 class.

```
int main()
{
     list1   LL1;
     list2   LL2;
}
```

now I would like to call a function merge that merges those two lists together. and takes the two objects of the lists as parameter.

lets call the function

```
void merge(object list1, object list2)
```

and so I can call it inside the main like that

```
merge(LL1, LL2);
```

is that possible ?

Comment: Where does the resultant merged list end up if space for it isn't passed into the method, nor does the method return the merged list? And is the merged list of type `list1` or type `list2`? Ignoring that question, you'd just do `void merge(list1& l1, list2& list2)` if you plan on modifying either of the input lists, or `void merge(const list1& l1, const list2& list2)` if not. But I'd definitely recommend doing some more basic C++ tutorials, it seems like you've not quite grasped the basic mechanics yet.

Comment: I am writing a function to merge two linked list. Trust me I understand the basics. Thanks for your philosophy. @RSahu

Comment: Not to be rude, but you just asked how to pass objects as method parameters. You clearly do *not* have a handle on the basics. If you had read an introductory tutorial such as [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/), you'd already have your answer.

Comment: To soften my previous comment, C++ is a harsh mistress. If you don't spend the time to make sure you have a very solid grasp on how the language works before you get into more complex constructs, it will chew you up and spit you out (and by that I mean you'll write lots of very, very buggy code). We were all there once, there's no shame in it. C++ is just much less forgiving than other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to pass an object as a parameter.

```
class list {

      //some functions

};

list merge(const list& l1, const list& l2)
{
  list mergedList;
  //logic to merge l1 and l2 and copy it to mergedList
  return mergedList;
}

int main()
{
     list   LL1;
     list   LL2;

     list mergedList = merge(LL1, LL2);
}
```

Comment: This will create copies of the lists passed to `merge`, likely not what the OP intends especially since there is no way for `merge` to return anything at the moment.

Comment: It's still creating needless copies. They should be either references or const references.

Comment: list merge(list& l1, lis&t l2) is what I believe @aruisdante means